# How do you disable touchscreen on Acer Iconia Windows 8 Tablet?

Tags: windows-8, tablet, touchscreen

I have a windows 8 acer Iconia touchscreen tablet.
I was tracing an image onto paper on it, but it kept sensing me and I couldn't complete the tracing without the screen changing. So, I was wondering if there is a way to temporarily disable it. How do I disable it so it doesn't sense my touches?

Comment: What kind of tablet?  Why would you want to disable a touch screen on a primarily touch device?

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable driver in Device Manager.
Run devmgmt.msc, identify touch device and disable the driver.

Comment: Sounds to me like [a global solution to a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx), but I suppose it *does* accomplish what the OP is after...